# Watin to download webpage loaded by javascript

Tags: html, web-scraping, watin

I am trying to download a webpage (printer web portal) with Watin but all I get is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta content="text/javascript" http-equiv="Content-Script-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=js_error.xml">
</noscript>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff" LINK="#000000" ALINK="#ff0000" VLINK="#000000" onload="init();location.replace('./system.xml');">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Even when I go to "View Page Source" in Firefox or IE, I don't get the "full" HTML.  However, Firebug  shows the full HTML.

Seems that the HTML is loaded by javascript afterwards, but how do I obtain this data?

Comment: `Firebug shows the full HTML.` then use firebug to get it

Comment: @Musa Wow Musa, way to be a condescending prick.  Did you miss the web-scraping tag?